# ContextualHelp on Infragistics XamFormulaEditor for custom variables

Tags: infragistics

I am using DataGrid for displaying table. One of the columns in Datagrid consists of XamFormulaEditor. Also, there are some custom variables that are assigned to XamCalculationManager's Named references so that they are visible to user when he types formula in XamFormulaEditor. I have couple of problems with ContextualHelp:

1. For Eg. if the custom variable name is "a", then in ContextualHelp list it looks like [//a]. Isnt't there any settings to make it look like [a] ?
2. Is there any way to filter the contextual help to not display standard functions and only display variables that we want ?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this and doing some research, ContextualHelp on Infragistics XamFormulaEditor for custom variables has been determined to be a new product idea. You can suggest new product ideas for future versions (or vote for existing ones) at Infragistics new site for features:

http://ideas.infragistics.com.

There are many benefits to submitting an product idea:
-          Direct communication with our product management team regarding your product idea.
-          Notifications whenever new information regarding your idea becomes available.
-          Ability to vote on your favorite product ideas to let us know which ones are the most important to you.  You will have ten votes for this and can change which ideas you are voting for at any time.
-          Allow you to shape the future of our products by requesting new controls and products altogether.
-          You and other developers can discuss existing product ideas with members of our Product Management team.
Steps to create your idea:

1. Log into the Infragistics Product Idea site at http://ideas.infragistics.com (creating a new login if needed).
2. Navigate to the product / platform channel of your choice (e.g. WPF, Windows Forms, ASP.NET, HTML5 / Ignite UI, iOS / NucliOS, etc.)
3. Add your product idea and be sure to be specific and provide as much detail as possible. Explain the context in which a feature would be used, why it is needed, why it can’t be accomplished today, and who would benefit from it. You can even add screenshots to build a stronger case. Remember that for your suggestion to be successful, you need other members of the community to vote for it. Be convincing!
   The Product Idea site puts you in the driver’s seat and allows you to track the progress of your ideas at any time, see how many votes it got, read comments from other developers in the community, and see if someone from the product team has additional questions for you.